# search all fields for a value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to search for a specific varchar value across all fields in a SQL Server DB?

Comment: Sure, take a look [here](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm) and [here](http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2007/11/02/How+To+Search+Every+Table+And+Field+In+A+SQL+Server+Database.aspx). Also [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1522).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need full text search http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx